# How to handle HTTP session in mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have some rest services in mule , I need to authenticate before each call. for that one I'm planning to make a login service first and session checking for later requests. is the right approach or please advice How to handle HTTP session in mule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the session yourself, using whatever shared data store across your Mule nodes to persist the session data.